# Insertar 'N' veces de registros con los mismos inputs

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes, quisiera saber en donde está mi error ya que no me funciona lo que ustedes dijeron arriba. coloqué un `print_r` y me dá el siguiente resultado...

```
 INSERT INTO trafos (centro) VALUES ('1')INSERT INTO trafos (centro) VALUES ('2')INSERT INTO trafos (centro) VALUES ('3')
```

es decir que teoricamente lo captura ok pero cuando lo guarda en la bdd solo guarda 1

```
<?php  

    $cantidadI=3;
    include_once('conexion.php');

    $centro =$_POST['centro'];

    foreach ($_POST['centro'] as $key=>$values) 
        { 
            $guardar="INSERT INTO trafos (centro) VALUES ('".$values['centro']."')";
            $result=mysql_query($guardar);
            mysql_close();
        }
 ?>

<div id="contenedor">

    <form id="datos" method="post" action="#">

    <div id="tabla" class="form-group">
            <table>
                <?php 

                    for ($i=1; $i<=$cantidad; $i++) { 
                ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                                <input id="centro" name="centro[<?php $i ?>][centro]" value="" type="text" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php
                    } 
                ?>
            </table>
            <br>
        </div>
        <input id="guarda"  type="submit" name="guarda" value="Guardar" />
        <input id="cance"   type="button" name="cance"  value="Cancelar" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: perdón pero es la primera vez que publico... en las próximas lo haré mejor

Comment: Escribí ese comentario antes de que se aprobara la edición cuando el código no estaba formateado y no se veía bien. La verdad es que ahora se ve mucho mejor. Dime si puedo asistir en algo o si necesitas ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

hola  viendo tu codigo lo unico que tienes mal es la forma de insertar el datos en la bd mira, aqui tienes un ejempo basico de como debieras hacerlo :

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

y el error que tambien veo es que no agregastes el ++ en el foreach, mira  un foreach es :

El constructor foreach proporciona un modo sencillo de iterar sobre arrays. foreach funciona sólo sobre arrays y objetos, y emitirá un error al intentar usarlo con una variable de un tipo diferente de datos o una variable no inicializada. Existen dos sintaxis:

```html
foreach (expresión_array as $valor)
    sentencias
foreach (expresión_array as $clave => $valor)
    sentencias
```

mas informacion : [manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

y lo que necesitas agregar es algo asi :

```html
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
    $age = $_POST['age'][$i];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('$name', '$age')");
    $i++;
  } 
}
```

solamente necesitas adaptalo al tuyo y listo si quieres mas sobre el codigo anterior puedes ver la pregunta en stackoverflow  en ingles : 
[question in english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156505/insert-multiple-fields-using-foreach-loop)

Comment: Las funciones `mysql_*` están obsoletas, se tendría que utilizar `mysqli_*` o `PDO`.

Comment: cierto perdon :(

Comment: Buenas tardes... error                                <?php  
 if ( isset($_POST['guarda']) )
  {
   $i = 0;  
   foreach ($_POST as $values) 
    { 
     $centro = $_POST['centro'][$i];
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO trafos (centro) VALUES ('$centro')");
     $i++;
    }
  }
?> el la mysql me graba en el lugar de colocar el numero de centro me coloca la palabra array